# Заголовок страницы

Tags: php, cms, javascript

Добрый день, как мне перехватить заголовок страницы (title) и внедрить данный JS код в php файл, чтобы вывести переменную с заголовком в нужном месте? Посоветуйте, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ловите через document.title . Но лучше, конечно, делать это средствами cms.
Да, а что значит "внедрить JS код в php"?

Comment: я хотел сразу код написать в файле <script> ... и затем вывести переменной. Мне для Virtuemarta надо. Joomla корректно заголовки выводит. есть встроеная функция для вывода тайтла, но она не правильно выводит

Comment: Можно распотрошить функцию, отвечающую за задание заголовка, посмотреть, что она изменяет и потом использовать эту переменную.  
Вариант на javascript: `<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById('hereGoesTitle').innerHTML = document.title;</script>`

Comment: я в программировании не силен. тут я так понимаю title страницы получается, а как его потом переменной присвоить и вывести ее в коде?
на примере покажу как сейчас:

$doc = &JFactory::getDocument();
$title_str = $doc->getTitle();
<div class="contentheading">'.$title_str.'</div>';
во так) и туда нужно вставить правильный заголовок.
title страницы определяется правильно, а вот эта функция почему то не правильно его получает.

Comment: Увы, с Joomla я помочь не могу. Но что-то мне подсказывает, что title страницы выставляется Виртмартом после того, как вы получаете его значение.

Comment: Я и написал, как я его получаю)) там функция уже предусмотрена. Можно попробовать вручную прописать свою функцию и вставить в файл, потом вывести переменной, но я в программирвоании не силен.